# Is the closure of a compact set compact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

While looking up information on compact operators I came across these two conflicting posts.

1. [If a set is compact then it is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255842/if-a-set-is-compact-then-it-is-closed)
2. [Topology: Example of a compact set but its closure not compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548865/topology-example-of-a-compact-set-but-its-closure-not-compact)

So the first link says that if a set $U$ is compact then it is closed. $U$ closed means $U = \overline{U}$ and hence $\overline{U}$ is compact. This seems to be in direct contradiction with the second post?

Comment: A compact subspace of a _Hausdorff_ space is closed.

Comment: @Watson That should be an answer, not just a comment :)

Comment: @csss: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176458

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a contradiction, because the main property is:

> A compact subspace $K$ of a *Hausdorff* space $X$ is closed.

Indeed, we show that for every $x \in X \setminus K$, there is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subset X \setminus K$. Fix such an $x$.

As $X$ is Hausdorff ($T2$), for every $y \in K$, there are disjoint open sets $U_y,V_y$ such that $x \in U_y$ and $y \in V_y$. Now you can use the compactness of $K \subset \bigcup_{y \in K} V_y$, so that 
$$K \subset \bigcup_{y \in E} V_y$$
for some finite subset $E \subset K$.

Define $U = \bigcap_{y \in E} U_y$, which is an open set because $E$ is finite. You can finally show that $U$ satisfies the desired conditions. I leave it to!

Comment: And I take it a non-Hausdorff space is a very uncommon space in applications? That is, when dealing with spaces such as $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Hilbert spaces such as $L^2(\Omega)$ and $W^{1, 2}(\Omega)$ then the closure of a compact set will be compact?

Comment: @csss: Yes, in general, e.g. in (functional) analysis, we are dealing with metric spaces, which are Hausdorff, so that the above property always holds.

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space such that every compact subspace is closed, then it is clearly $T1$. This doesn't imply $T2$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518787/.

Comment: @csss: In some branches of mathematics, non-Hausdorff spaces are more common. For example, in dynamics --- the study of group actions on topological spaces --- the *orbit space* or *quotient* of a group action is often non-Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the co-finite topology on R, the set of real numbers. Every subset of R is compact. However, it is not every subset of R is closed. There is a special spaces that assumed that every compact set is closed. Certainly, in Hausdorff spaces, every compact set is closed. For your the second question, Take X=R, the set of real numbers. Define topology on X by U is a subset of X is open if and only if U contains 1 or U is the empty set.Then K={1,2} is compact, but cl(K)=R which is not compact with this topology. Actually, every point x in not K, and any open subset U contain x then 1 is also in U. So, the intersection of U and K is not empty, then x is in the closure of K. Therefore, cl(K)=R. The collection U(x)={1,x} forms an open cover of X, obvious there is no finite sub-collection of it cover X.